# splitting pandas dataframe with columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with large numbers of columns. What I really want is to
create/split the dataframe. For example:

generating TOY data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10),columns = ['x'])
df['y'] = np.arange(30,40,1)
df['1'] = np.random.rand(10)
df['2'] = np.random.rand(10)
df['3'] = np.random.rand(10)
df['4'] = np.random.rand(10)
df['5'] = np.random.rand(10)
```

> df =

```
    x   y   1              2           3          4            5
0   0   30  0.047787    0.435396    0.926836    0.314469    0.477411
1   1   31  0.083536    0.258120    0.682284    0.025050    0.713777
2   2   32  0.201041    0.872864    0.050977    0.580314    0.185589
3   3   33  0.105833    0.974538    0.559265    0.128242    0.217965
4   4   34  0.146551    0.662001    0.936995    0.050702    0.249724
5   5   35  0.098615    0.854952    0.649501    0.509777    0.726458
6   6   36  0.387889    0.040331    0.902277    0.051822    0.354042
7   7   37  0.321591    0.823724    0.052266    0.081491    0.187576
8   8   38  0.983665    0.152271    0.530755    0.384810    0.844386
9   9   39  0.649185    0.776682    0.239589    0.654547    0.581337
```

What I really want is to split dataframe in such a way like as shown below:

df1 =

```
    x   y   1
0   0   30  0.047787
1   1   31  0.083536
2   2   32  0.201041
3   3   33  0.105833
4   4   34  0.146551
5   5   35  0.098615
6   6   36  0.387889
7   7   37  0.321591
8   8   38  0.983665
9   9   39  0.649185
```

df2 =

```
    x    y    2
0   0   30  0.435396
1   1   31  0.25812
2   2   32  0.872864
3   3   33  0.974538
4   4   34  0.662001
5   5   35  0.854952
6   6   36  0.040331
7   7   37  0.823724
8   8   38  0.152271
9   9   39  0.776682
```

And so on. Since I have large number of columns, so it is very difficult to do it one by one. Is there any simpler way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set *x* and *y* cols which would remain static throughout as the index axis 
and then perform a `groupby` across columns.

By utilizing a dictionary-comprehension, loop through every such groups. Additionally, a `reset_index` at the end would ensure that a flattened `DF` gets produced.

```
df.set_index(['x','y'], inplace=True)
dfs = {i:grp.reset_index() for i, grp in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)), axis=1)}
```

The keys of the resulting dictionary produced would constitute the column names which could be queried like:

```
dfs[0]
```

[image]

```
dfs[1]
```

[image]

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much  Nickil Maveli. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to automatically generate dataframes:

```
df_cuts = [df[['x', 'y', col]] for col in df.columns if col not in ['x', 'y']]
```

I verified the output in the command line:

```
for i in range(len(df_cuts)):
    print 'df %r:' % i
    print df_cuts[i]
    print '\n'
```

The result is such:

```
df 0:
   x   y         1
0  0  30  0.695465
1  1  31  0.425572
2  2  32  0.018986
3  3  33  0.165947
4  4  34  0.103120
5  5  35  0.069060
6  6  36  0.676640
7  7  37  0.492231
8  8  38  0.950436
9  9  39  0.156195


df 1:
   x   y         2
0  0  30  0.928538
1  1  31  0.019624
2  2  32  0.862811
3  3  33  0.289581
4  4  34  0.150975
5  5  35  0.835313
6  6  36  0.768760
7  7  37  0.396042
8  8  38  0.423745
9  9  39  0.268596


df 2:
   x   y         3
0  0  30  0.999175
1  1  31  0.004125
2  2  32  0.137457
3  3  33  0.042903
4  4  34  0.580698
5  5  35  0.663723
6  6  36  0.996608
7  7  37  0.960361
8  8  38  0.932486
9  9  39  0.758873


df 3:
   x   y         4
0  0  30  0.708976
1  1  31  0.547635
2  2  32  0.722322
3  3  33  0.912707
4  4  34  0.380471
5  5  35  0.607742
6  6  36  0.803980
7  7  37  0.569364
8  8  38  0.882297
9  9  39  0.954743


df 4:
   x   y         5
0  0  30  0.900532
1  1  31  0.247818
2  2  32  0.629371
3  3  33  0.502218
4  4  34  0.183292
5  5  35  0.875611
6  6  36  0.940828
7  7  37  0.200641
8  8  38  0.874052
9  9  39  0.525997
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you could set index to `['x','y']` and then just get your columns by column names:

```
>>> df2 = df.set_index(['x','y'])
>>> df2
             1         2         3         4
x y                                         
0 30  0.161017  0.280965  0.058429  0.750003
1 31  0.643460  0.258441  0.951750  0.774355
2 32  0.948439  0.573363  0.126369  0.577629
3 33  0.896542  0.722825  0.927644  0.470369
4 34  0.298559  0.009676  0.841103  0.899220
5 35  0.855292  0.849880  0.529132  0.929805
6 36  0.428680  0.486381  0.271048  0.219826
7 37  0.752370  0.698653  0.980554  0.894405
8 38  0.027857  0.085865  0.086936  0.403528
9 39  0.522483  0.646266  0.825819  0.574025

>>> df2['1']
x  y 
0  30    0.161017
1  31    0.643460
2  32    0.948439
3  33    0.896542
4  34    0.298559
5  35    0.855292
6  36    0.428680
7  37    0.752370
8  38    0.027857
9  39    0.522483
```

if you just need to loop through the columns, you can do this:

```
>>> for i in range(1,5):
...     print df[['x','y',str(i)]]
... 
   x   y         1
0  0  30  0.161017
1  1  31  0.643460
2  2  32  0.948439
3  3  33  0.896542
4  4  34  0.298559
5  5  35  0.855292
6  6  36  0.428680
7  7  37  0.752370
8  8  38  0.027857
9  9  39  0.522483
   x   y         2
0  0  30  0.280965
1  1  31  0.258441
2  2  32  0.573363
3  3  33  0.722825
4  4  34  0.009676
5  5  35  0.849880
6  6  36  0.486381
7  7  37  0.698653
8  8  38  0.085865
9  9  39  0.646266
   x   y         3
0  0  30  0.058429
1  1  31  0.951750
2  2  32  0.126369
3  3  33  0.927644
4  4  34  0.841103
5  5  35  0.529132
6  6  36  0.271048
7  7  37  0.980554
8  8  38  0.086936
9  9  39  0.825819
   x   y         4
0  0  30  0.750003
1  1  31  0.774355
2  2  32  0.577629
3  3  33  0.470369
4  4  34  0.899220
5  5  35  0.929805
6  6  36  0.219826
7  7  37  0.894405
8  8  38  0.403528
9  9  39  0.574025
```